# Could you please provide me with some advice on why the splash_image set using flutter_native_splash is not appearing only on Android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to implement a splash screen in my Flutter app, but the splash screen is only not appearing on Android. It displays fine on iOS without any issues. I have already checked for any mistakes in file names and directory structure.

pubspeck.yaml

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image_android: 'assets/images/splash/splash.png'
  image_ios: 'assets/images/splash/splash.png'
  color: '#ffffff'
  image_dark: 'assets/images/splash/splash.png'
  color_dark: '#231E1E'
  android_12:
    image: 'assets/images/splash/splash_android12.png'
    icon_background_color: '#ffffff'
    image_dark: 'assets/images/splash/splash_android12.png'
    icon_background_color_dark: '#231E1E'
```

The background is displaying correctly, but only the image is not showing up. The size of the image is `961 * 960`, and the Android version is 12.

`flutter doctor`

```
✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.5)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```